# Converting "System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser" to "OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver"

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, converters

I have a problem, because I don't know how to convert "System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser" to "OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver". This is my code:

```
IWebDriver driver = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as WebBrowser;
```

I'm glad of your help.

Comment: What makes you think you can convert between those two?

Comment: I have error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver'. An expicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`, a class that is part of the .NET Framework’s base class library, does not implement `OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver`, which is an interface defined by the open-source Selenium project. If you are trying to automate an embedded web browser in a .NET Windows Forms app, there is no directly supported way to do so using only the Selenium project’s library. It might be possible to do by using Selenium with a companion project like WinAppDriver, but you would need to confirm that for yourself.